# "Module was built without symbols" error appeared after Visual studio 2012 upgrade

Tags: c++, windows, dll, symbols

I was previously using visual studio 2012, but after a recent windows upgrade it started to complain that it is now incompatible. I upgraded windows 7 and incompatibility message went away from Visual studio 2012, but I have a new problem now. The solutions that were running before are not running now. I am using a proprietary libary (cdt.dll and cdt.lib files) for my script.

Visual studio is now producing the following message I have not seen before:

```
'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded  C:\Users\CCPAdmin\Desktop\cpp\cpp_applications\extract by block\tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2\Debug\tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\CCPAdmin\Desktop\cpp\cpp_applications\extract by block\tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2\Debug\cdt.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

The program '[8104] tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I presume the problem is the cdt.dll **"Module was built without symbols"**.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

`The program '[8104] tmt_gygi_700ms120mlmin_mob_f2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).` means your application ran succesfully. The message you're seeing simply means there is no debug info available and isn't a concern (unless you want to debug `cdt.dll` in which case you need compatible pdb files).

Answer (score 2):

If it is Python, go to project->Properties->Debug-> uncheck 'Enable native code debugging'

For C++ , go to tools-> options->debugging->general->uncheck 'Enable just my code'

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem now using VS 2017 15.9.11 when tried to debug some test, my message error was:

> 'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\pt-BR\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\pt-BR\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   The program '[6308] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I've solved by adding `[TestClass]` annotation in the class declaration.
VS doesn't have a clear message to this error.